# How can I use Django to transform checkboxes into radio buttons while retaining the logic of checkboxes and use them in my form?

Tags: django, button, checkbox, radio-button, customization

I'd like to know how to customise a function on Django that would allow me to transform checkboxes into radio buttons, while retaining the logic of checkboxes. Let me explain:
I've created a form on Django, but my form has several fields containing checkboxes with distinct behaviours depending on the field. But for the most part, the functionalities that can be observed on these checkboxes are :

- The ability to check and uncheck a box (normal functionality)
- Two checkboxes in a group of checkboxes cannot be checked simultaneously (uniqueness of checkboxes)
- If a checkbox encapsulates a field, then checking the box reveals the hidden field and unchecking the box or checking another box automatically hides the field encapsulated by the previous checkbox.
  But I haven't found any resources in the Django documentation that could help me with this task, especially as when I tried to implement the client-side logic with JavaScript/jQuery, when I submitted my form on a web page, it generated validation errors in my checkboxes, implying that the logic implemented on the client side didn't find a match on the server side, so I'm a bit at a loss, I've been working on this code for a while now, and I'm hardly making any progress.

The end result of this piece of code should allow me to manage this example case in my form:
Field label: Fever
Response option with checkboxes linked to the fever field: Yes, No, DK (Don't Know)
If the user ticks the Yes box, a hidden message appears asking for the date of onset of symptoms. If the user unchecks the Yes box or ticks one of the other two boxes, i.e. No or DK, this automatically hides the hidden field encapsulated by the Yes option. Knowing that at the end the submission of my form should not generate validation errors on the checkboxes.

I created this Django code below:

```
from django import forms

class CustomCheckbox(forms.CheckboxInput):
    def __init__(self, choices=None, hidden_fields_mapping=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.choices = choices
        self.hidden_fields_mapping = hidden_fields_mapping
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        attrs['data-group'] = name  # Ajout de l'attribut data-group
        html = super().render(name, value, attrs, renderer)
        html += f"<script>initCustomCheckbox('{attrs['id']}', {self.hidden_fields_mapping})</script>"
        return html
```

This CustomCheckbox class adds extra functionality to checkboxes by using custom HTML attributes and JavaScript to customise their appearance and behaviour.
But that doesn't help me, because it doesn't work. I would have liked it if, when I called this class in a field of my form with checkboxes, it could have handled it according to the specifics defined upstream.

Comment: Have you tried to fully dismantle the form to all its bound fields with all its methods within the template like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually). That should allow you to add custom individual classes to every field of your form.

Comment: Yes, I've done it, but the problem remains, I don't know if the problem comes from my JavaScript/jQuery script or from my forms.py file, in short I'd like to post practically all the form code, the html and JavaScript code. I've done everything, but first I'm having problems with the display and then I can't submit my form.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do things like this. It's quite a bit of work on the client side (well, it was for me, since I'm not fluent in JS/JQuery or DOM navigation).

If what you want is a few common choices as radio buttons and an "Other" button to reveal a  TextInput, then the following will do it for you.

If this isn't exactly what you want, I hope it's a source of ideas...

In a form:

```
field = forms.CharField( ...  initial='?', ...
    widget =  ChoicesWithOtherWidget(
            attrs={ 'data-radio':'?__Specify',
            '   data-radio-labels':'Unspecified__Specify',  },
        ),
```

will display as a radio button labelled "Unspecified" which will return a
question-mark, and a radio button labelled "Specify". If that one is clicked,
then a regular CharField widget will appear and anything you type into it will
be returned. You can have multiple buttons and you can omit the labels if the value is also suitable as the label. This displays four buttons labelled and returning 100, 200, 381, 525 and a fifth to reveal the TextInput box

```
field = forms.IntegerField( ...
    widget = ChoicesWithOtherWidget(
            attrs={ 'data-radio':'100__200__381__525__Other',  },
```

The widget code (and a form and a view for testing)

```
class ChoicesWithOtherWidget( forms.TextInput):
    """ creates radiobuttons for common choices but can input anything through "other"

    The radiobutton choices are supplied as "data-radio" attr on the TextInput widget, and
    their labels (which default to the choice) as  the "data-radio-labels" attr

    Its all done with Jquery. See the media file for more info
    """
    class Media:
        js = ( 'utils/choices_with_other_widget.js', )
        css = { 'all': ( 'utils/choices_with_other_widget.css',  )} # .inline-choices-with-other

    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        super().__init__( attrs)
        self.attrs['class'] = ' '.join([ 'with-radio', self.attrs.get('class', '') ])

# testing the above needs a full JS browser. Easier just to make sure this works...

from django.views.generic import FormView

class ChoicesWithOtherTestForm( forms.Form):
    foo = forms.CharField(
        widget = ChoicesWithOtherWidget(
            attrs={
                #'class':'with-radio',  # built into widget
                'data-radio':'foo__bar__other',
                'data-radio-labels': 'foolish__barfacious',
        }),
    )

class ChoicesWithOtherTestView( FormView):
    form_class = ChoicesWithOtherTestForm
    template_name = 'jobs/simple_form.html'
    title='Test View'
    def form_valid( self, form):
        #DEBUG( self, form.cleaned_data)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(
            reverse( 'wafers:ok') + f"?foo={form.cleaned_data['foo']}" # easy to test
        )
```

`utils/choices_with_other_widget.js` (which goes in your `MEDIA_ROOT` which is `/static` at present in my project on the dev server )

```
$(document).ready( function(){

// this converts a simple Django TextInput (CharField etc) into a choices + other
// inputter if it has attr "with-radio".
//
// The radiobutton choices are supplied as data-radio attr on the TextInput widget, and
// their labels (which default to the choice) as  the data-radio-labels attr
//
// tested that this DOM navigation works with form.as_table, _as_p and _as_ul.
//
// this was a lot more work than I expected!

$('input.with-radio').each( function(){
    var data = $(this).attr('data-radio').split('__') ;
    var labs = $(this).attr('data-radio-labels')
    var labels = ( labs === undefined ) ? [] : labs.split('__');
    var last_data = data[ data.length-1 ];
    var where = this;               // the input element
    $(where).removeAttr("required");  // make not required
    var id = $(this).attr('id') ;
    var name = $(this).attr('name')  ;
    //console.log( `data=${data} id=${id} last_data=${last_data}` )

    $.each( data, function(i, opt){
        var label = (labels[i] === undefined ) ? opt : labels[i] ;

        var button = $(
            `<div class="inline-choices-with-other ${name}-radio-inline">
            <label for="${id}_x${i}" > ${label}&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="radio" class="radio-2"
                id="${id}_x${i}" name="${name}" value="${opt}" />
            </div>`
            );
        //button.css('min-width', '100px'); //better in style sheet for the form
                                          // but this works nicely to avoid irregular spacing
        var new_button = $(where).before(button)

    });

    var radio_buttons = $(where).siblings(`div.${name}-radio-inline`).find('input');
    var last_button = $(radio_buttons).last();

    $(radio_buttons).slice(0,-1).each( function(){  // all but the last
        $(this).on('click', function(){
            $(where).hide();
            $(where).removeAttr("required");

            //needed clicking twice to fully un-select the "other" box
            // next line and later test  prevents a possible infinite recursion

            var trigger_needed = ( $(where).attr('name') == name  );

            $(where).attr( 'name', name+'___');    // hidden input submit name changed
            $(last_button).attr( 'name', name);    // so this button is part of the radio group

            if( trigger_needed) { $(this).trigger('click') };
        });

        // on an error redisplay the clicked radio button will be cleared
        // and the value will be in the inputbox. so, re-do the relevant click

        var val = $(where).val()
        var thisval = $(this).val()
        console.log( `${name}: ${val} thisval ${thisval}` )
        if ( $(this).val() == val ){ $(this).trigger('click') };
    });
    $( last_button).on( 'click', function(){        // the last ("other")
        $(where).show();
        $(where).attr( 'name', name );              // opposite of above
        $(last_button).attr( 'name', name+'___');
    });

    // if a radio button "owns" this value, our name will now be ___name. If
    // not and there's a value to show, don't hide  it.
    if ( !$(where).val()  || $(where).attr('name') !== name ){
        $(where).hide();                          // until last button "other" clicked
    } else {
        $( last_button).trigger('click')
    };

    $(where).before( '<span>&emsp;</span>');  //cosmetic

});
}); // end document.ready
```

and the css file `utils/choices_with_other_widget.js` (same location)

```
/* All of this except min-width is copied from .radio-inline
 * this is "external* style sheet which can be overridden
 * by an "internal" one eg Django { { block extracss } }
*/

.inline-choices-with-other {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;

  min-width: 100px;  /* this is the main one to tune for "columns" */
}

input.radio-2 {
  float: right;      /* radio buttons on right of their div (above) */
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nigel for your reply, but that's not quite what I need, in fact I've realised that Django doesn't have any documentation on the subject, so it may be up to me to implement a custom class that can help me manage my checkboxes like radio buttons without them actually being radio buttons. I think that if I manage to implement it, it will be a new feature that Django should take into account.